# Unable to connect to MySql db from Airflow

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, airflow, devops

So I have 2 EC2s in a single VPC. One EC2 is running airflow, the other ec2 is running a wordpress db.

I've created a new Airflow job that uses the MySqlHook to connect to the wordpress db.

```
mysql_hook = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='wp')
```

however, when I run the above code, I get the following response:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '{PRODHOSTURL}.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)")
```

I've tried making sure there are inbound rules that allow for 3306 port connections on the wordpress db. I've tried adding bind address rules to the .conf file for mysql. I've checked and re-checked the db rules. But nothing is working. Any ideas?

PS The airflow ec2 has many jobs, most of which connect to other dbs in this same VPC...so I don't know why MySql is acting differently. Could I use a different hook?

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find the mysql connection logs? I want to see if we're even reaching the wp db

Comment: Could you check if you are able to access mysql from the machine/container in which your worker is running? Something like `telnet <mysql-host> <mysql-port>`

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer. The security rules were incorrect. To troubleshoot, i went to one machine and ran the command "ping {other machine's ip address}" until I could get through, in both directions. Then re-ran the code, and it worked. Thanks!